# Make explosion animation SKaction and remove

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I want to make a animation to my game when two sprite nodes have a collision. So i create this function :

```
func contactEntreMeteorites(Meteorites : SKSpriteNode , Meteorites2 : SKSpriteNode){

        Meteorites.removeFromParent()
        Meteorites2.removeFromParent()

        let ExplosionTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion1.png")
        let ExplosionTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion2.png")
        let ExplosionTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion3.png")
        let ExplosionTexture4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion4.png")
        let ExplosionTexture5 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion5.png")
        let ExplosionTexture6 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion6.png")
        let ExplosionTexture7 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion7.png")
        let ExplosionTexture8 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion8.png")
        let ExplosionTexture9 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion9.png")
        let ExplosionTexture10 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion10.png")
        let ExplosionTexture11 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion11.png")
        let ExplosionTexture12 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion12.png")

        let animateExplosion = SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(0, withRange: 0),
            SKAction.animateWithTextures([ExplosionTexture1,ExplosionTexture2,ExplosionTexture3,ExplosionTexture4,ExplosionTexture5,ExplosionTexture6,ExplosionTexture7,ExplosionTexture8,ExplosionTexture9,ExplosionTexture10,ExplosionTexture11,ExplosionTexture12 ], timePerFrame: 0.1)
            ])

        Explosion = SKSpriteNode(texture: ExplosionTexture1)
        Explosion.position = CGPointMake(Meteorites.position.x, Meteorites.position.y)
        Explosion.runAction(animateExplosion)
        self.addChild(Explosion)

    }
```

This code works perfectly but I don't know how can I delete the `SpriteNode` "Explosion" when my `SKAction sequence` animateExplosion is finished.

Thanks for helping :) And sorry for my english i'm french ;)

Comment: You should really use a loop to populate an array of textures, and then pass this array to `animateWithTextures`.

Comment: How can i make this loop ?

Comment: Something like `for var i = 1; i <= 12; i++ { explosionTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "Explosion\(i).png")) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've implemented the wrong method. Instead of `runAction:`, implement `runAction:completion:`. The `completion` method will be called *on completion!* So that is the place to remove the explosion node.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution :

```
Explosion = SKSpriteNode(texture: ExplosionTexture1)
        Explosion.position = CGPointMake(Meteorites.position.x, Meteorites.position.y)
        self.addChild(Explosion)
        Explosion.runAction(animateExplosion, completion : {self.Explosion.removeFromParent()})
```

Comment: This isn't a forum; you don't need to post "thanks" as an answer.  Accept matt's answer instead, which you have done.

Comment: Ok , i will not do this again ^^